# Load current node from block and from display suite field

Tags: entities, nodes

Sorry if this question is too obvious, I need to load the current node from display suite and then execute this php code:

```
<?php

$project = node_load(5);

foreach ($project->field_gallery['und'] as $val ) {
  echo '<img src="' . $val['filename']  . '">';
}

?>
```

In display suite I tried:

```
$project = node_load($nid);

and

$project = $entity->nid;
```

I also tried the same within a block, and it failed. It only works when I set a static id as node_load(5).

Please, can I get the answer how to load the node from display suite custom field and from a simple block?

Edit: I'm adding a custom field to display suite from this url:
 /admin/structure/ds/fields/manage_custom
Structure > Display Suite > Fields > Add a code field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the node id from node page using [arg](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) function...

> Returns a component of the current Drupal path.
>
> When viewing a page at the path "admin/structure/types", for example,
>   arg(0) returns "admin", arg(1) returns "structure", and arg(2) returns
>   "types".

node pages always has path 'node/nid' so arg(1) gives node id...

```
$nid = arg(1);
$node = node_load($nid);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works from block. Can you suggest how to get it to work from display suite?

Comment: Regarding "how to load the node from display suite custom field", can you please explain where you are writing code ? What did you try regarding above ? Can you update your question with more details ?

Comment: Sure. I updated my question. I tried it with $project = $entity->nid;